# Get current location without using GPS, Wifi and cell tower

Tags: ios, location

Is there any way to get current location without using GPS, Wifi and cell tower.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? You could take a screenshot of the sky, analyze the star formations and, correlate it with the time information and calculate the geo position from that!?

Comment: How accurate do you want this?

Comment: @luk2302 but still luk, how can you send that screenshot  without wifi and cell tower .. :D

Comment: @Bhavin he did not say anything about sending the data anywhere.

Comment: IP geo-location is not an option too?

Comment: @ergonaut: do you know any way to find that, i need it as accurate as possible.

Comment: can you use another frequency, perhaps with an additional receiver?  For example, if you listen on FM bands, the local radio stations should tell you which country you are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the lattitude roughly and with big errors, if you analyse the magnetic field, especially if you can ask the user to place the phone on a flat surface, even better if you can ask him or her to have it point north (but that might prove unreliable).

Subsequently ask the user to point the phone to the sun. Use that information to derive the longitude, given that you know time and time zone the phone is set to.